# Exploding dates from annual to monthly

Tags: r

I have annual *book value per share (bps)* data which needs to be blown out to a monthly time series.  I want to join it with a monthly price series to compute monthly *Price to Book (P/B)*.

My monthly data looks like this (`dput` below):

```
  date      |    bps
------------------------
2012-06-29  |   2.44376
2013-06-28  |   1.73054
2014-06-30  |   1.68171
2015-06-30  |   2.07297
2016-06-30  |   1.77073
```

What I want is to roll forward all the data points to appear on a monthly basis:

```
  date      |    bps
------------------------
2012-06-29  |   2.44376
2012-07-31  |   2.44376
2012-08-31  |   2.44376
  ...             ...
2013-05-31  |   2.44376
2013-06-28  |   1.73054
  ...             ...
```

and so on.  Does anyone know a slick, non-for-loop way of doing this in R?

Here's a toy version of my bps data frame:

```
df = structure(list(date = structure(c(1340892000, 1372341600, 1404050400, 
1435586400, 1467208800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), bps = 
c(2.44376, 1.73054, 1.68171, 2.07297, 1.77073)), .Names = c("date", 
"bps"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 5L))
```

Comment: Please include some relevant data in your example, such as data from other months. Can't reproduce what you're asking with data only from June.

Comment: @AdamQuek - looks like `bps` just repeats for every month up until the next year takes over. The question seems fine to me.

Comment: @thelatemail - correct.  The data repeats every year on the last business day of a specific month (in this case, June).  I want to take that annual data and roll it forward, repeating every month.

Comment: But isn't the `df` already "appearing on a monthly basis", i.e. `2012-06-28, 2013-06-27, 2014-06-29, 2015-06-29, 2016-06-29`

Comment: @AdamQueck:  no, the points are annual.  I only have data every June, and I want data every June, July, August, September, October, November, December, January, February, March, April and May.

Comment: @AdamQuek - you misinterpret - OP has data for June each year, they want to replicate the values they have for each month from July until the following May, when the next case picks up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with the dates of the month that aren't the first is a bit tricky, but you can get a sequence easily enough with `seq.POSIXt`. Using lubridate to munge dates,

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% mutate(date = ceiling_date(date, 'month'),
              date = map2(date, 
                          lead(date - 1, default = last(date)), 
                          seq, by = 'month')) %>% 
    unnest() %>% 
    mutate(date = date - days(1))

#>        bps       date
#> 1  2.44376 2012-06-30
#> 2  2.44376 2012-07-31
#> 3  2.44376 2012-08-31
#> 4  2.44376 2012-09-30
#> 5  2.44376 2012-10-31
#> 6  2.44376 2012-11-30
#> 7  2.44376 2012-12-31
#> 8  2.44376 2013-01-31
#> 9  2.44376 2013-02-28
#> 10 2.44376 2013-03-31
#> 11 2.44376 2013-04-30
#> 12 2.44376 2013-05-31
#> 13 1.73054 2013-06-30
#> 14 1.73054 2013-07-31
#> 15 1.73054 2013-08-31
#> 16 1.73054 2013-09-30
#> 17 1.73054 2013-10-31
#> 18 1.73054 2013-11-30
#> 19 1.73054 2013-12-31
#> 20 1.73054 2014-01-31
#> 21 1.73054 2014-02-28
#> 22 1.73054 2014-03-31
#> 23 1.73054 2014-04-30
#> 24 1.73054 2014-05-31
#> 25 1.68171 2014-06-30
#> 26 1.68171 2014-07-31
#> 27 1.68171 2014-08-31
#> 28 1.68171 2014-09-30
#> 29 1.68171 2014-10-31
#> 30 1.68171 2014-11-30
#> 31 1.68171 2014-12-31
#> 32 1.68171 2015-01-31
#> 33 1.68171 2015-02-28
#> 34 1.68171 2015-03-31
#> 35 1.68171 2015-04-30
#> 36 1.68171 2015-05-31
#> 37 2.07297 2015-06-30
#> 38 2.07297 2015-07-31
#> 39 2.07297 2015-08-31
#> 40 2.07297 2015-09-30
#> 41 2.07297 2015-10-31
#> 42 2.07297 2015-11-30
#> 43 2.07297 2015-12-31
#> 44 2.07297 2016-01-31
#> 45 2.07297 2016-02-29
#> 46 2.07297 2016-03-31
#> 47 2.07297 2016-04-30
#> 48 2.07297 2016-05-31
#> 49 1.77073 2016-06-30
```

Comment: Row 34 looks suspicious - `#> 34 1.68171 2015-03-01 10:00:00`

Comment: @alistaire Thanks, but I really need end of month.  Last calendar day of the month is okay because I have a cute `previous_business_day_if_weekend` function (tucked away somewhere) which I can apply to the entire date column.

Comment: @thelatemail Yeah, it skips February. I guess `seq.POSIXt` is adding some normalized amount of days instead of just incrementing the month?

Comment: @alistaire - yep, a "month" is not very well defined so R generally doesn't play nicely when doing date operations using them.

Comment: @lebelinoz Edited to round to the last day of the month. It introduces a new dependency, but `base::round.POSIXt` doesn't round to the month.

Comment: Actually, I've just realised that my data changes month-ends at some point in history (my company previously had a May year-end, but switched to June in 2000).  What I like about this answer is that it copes with the potential changes to the months.

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly pretty, but add a month, roll back a day and away you go:

```
tmp <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)),each=12),]
mon <- as.numeric(format(tmp$date,"%m")) + 1:12

tmp$date <- as.POSIXct(paste(
  as.numeric(format(tmp$date,"%Y")) + (mon > 12),
  rep(month.abb,2)[mon],
  "01",
  sep="-"
), format="%Y-%b-%d") - as.difftime(1,units="days")

tmp
#           date     bps
#1    2012-06-30 2.44376
#1.1  2012-07-31 2.44376
#1.2  2012-08-31 2.44376
#1.3  2012-09-30 2.44376
#1.4  2012-10-31 2.44376
#1.5  2012-11-30 2.44376
#1.6  2012-12-31 2.44376
#1.7  2013-01-31 2.44376
#1.8  2013-02-28 2.44376
#1.9  2013-03-31 2.44376
#1.10 2013-04-30 2.44376
#1.11 2013-05-31 2.44376
#2    2013-06-30 1.73054
#2.1  2013-07-31 1.73054
#2.2  2013-08-31 1.73054
# etc etc
```